# Juice injector throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Am trying to learn google juice. I have a InstallConfigurationModule class which has all the dependency needed to create an object of typeA and TypeB  .And, got a class say class Car as shown Below and am trying to do constructor injection. When the run method is called am getting null pointer exception at system.out.println line.I know for sure that ModuleA,ModuleB has refrence on creating TypeA,TypeB since in my 
 InstallConfigurationModulemodule, if I say Bind(TypeA.class)or Bind(TypeB.class), I get google juice error, 'A binding to typeA or typeB already configured'.

```
public class InstallConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new ModuleA());
        install(new ModuleB());
    }
}
public class Car

{
  private Type A;
  private Type B;

@inject
  void SetCar(Type A, Type B)//not the constructor
 {
   this.A=A;
   this.B=B;
}

private void run()
{
  System.out.println(A.toString()) //throw null pointer exception
}
```

what Worked:

```
private void run()
    { 
     Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new 
                         InstallConfigurationModule());

    TypeA typeA =injector.getInstance(TypeA.class);
      System.out.println(A.toString()) //works fine

    }
```

Why do I get NPE when I try to do without creatingInjector. Any help appreciated.

PS: very new to juice.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that we have the below components:

- a class interface

```
public interface Type {}
```

- an interface implementation

```
public class TypeImpl implements Type {
    private String name;

    public TypeImpl(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {return name.toString();}
}
```

- a configuration module

```
public class InstallConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.configure();

        // new ModuleA()
        bind(Type.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("a")).toInstance((Type) new TypeImpl("a"));
        // new ModuleB()
        bind(Type.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("b")).toInstance((Type) new TypeImpl("b"));
    }
}
```

that it doesn't use the install method, but you can use it; the configure method uses the Names.named API to mark a TypeImpl as "a" and another one as "b".

We have to put the @Named and @Inject annotations in the Car class

```
import com.google.inject.name.Named;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Car {
    private Type a;
    private Type b;

    @Inject
    public void setA(@Named("a") Type a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setB(@Named("b") Type b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void methodIsCalled(){
        run();
    }

    private void run() {
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
}
```

So the injector will know how to configure the Type instances.

Finally, in the main or configuration class, we have the below statements

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new InstallConfigurationModule());
        Car car = injector.getInstance(Car.class);

        // method that it calss the run method
        car.methodIsCalled();
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
a
b
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I use install module, it knows how to construct the ObjectA, ObjectB right?. Also, Say I don't have the need to call some method of Car class from main.  Should I still create the injector instance for a car?. I don't see the point of what am missing to get NPE.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Yes, the framework knows how to build new instances when it charges the module. Injector instance is mandatory, but it depends on the app that you are creating. The injector creates the instances of classes and it resolves the annotations and it initializes the field in the class; without the injector the classes are empty.